# Dell N5110 - Byte-DM5710BT paired but not connecting

Tags: bluetooth

I paired Byte-DM5710BT Bluetooth headset successfully but not able to connect, I am also using bluetooth mouse and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Bluetooth Manager (search for `blueman` in the Sofware Center) and it should work. (It worked for me and my friend; we both have XPS 15.)